# Online manual in "Book" format, like DocBook, but providing collarborative editing like mediawiki?

Tags: publishing, collaboration

I have a reference document for some software that I would like to publish online, and to provide a pdf and multi-page html version.
DocBook looks idea for this, similar to how subversion publish their manual;
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

However I would like to be able to collaboratively edit the document on the similar to google docs, or mediawiki.

I am using lots of equations so LaTax support is highly sought after.

Any suggestions on what I can use?

I have looked at the Heirarchy and DocBook plugins for wikipedia, but they seem old and unmaintained and I couldn't get them to work as I want.

Answer (score 3):

For a wiki-based solution, you could take a look at [Instiki](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/HomePage).  It uses a program called [itexToMML](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/itex2MML.html) to convert a subset of LaTeX mathematical syntax to MathML.  Normal text is entered using a variant of Markdown.

For an example thereof, take a look at the [nLab](http://ncatlab.org).